# Getting some errors on setActionBar()

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx

So i'm having some trouble with my code with this error
i'm using androidx and i think the problem is because of dat.
for being honest i don't know how to change to old version android

so the error is this

```
error: incompatible types: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.widget.Toolbar
```

I already tried to import android.support.v7.wigdet.Toolbar did not work :(

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;



import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

**nav_header.xml**
[image]

**activity_main.xml**
[image: **activity_main.xml**]

**Build.gradle**
[image]

Update error when run

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.readytogo, PID: 8403
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.readytogo/com.example.readytogo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:536)
        at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:53)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3553)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:104)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6929)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:326)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at com.example.readytogo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

Comment: Share your `activity_main` layout file with question

Comment: Post your .xml and Gradle dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;



import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

As you are extending from `AppComatActivity` instead of `Activity`, so you have to use `setSupportActionBar` instead of `setActionBar`.

IN your xml Toolbar is also missing, you need to add toolbar in your activity xml like

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolBarStyle" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, so the error gone but now i have one problem when i try to run the app on emulator it crashes                      
           <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

Comment: Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Comment: Do you have intent-filter in your Activity tag in Manifest File?

<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: please share the activity xml, line 26 where it says the error present

Comment: this?  <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: try by changing fragment to
 <androidx.fragment.app.Fragment />

Answer (score 2):

If you looking to use androidx dependency then your code must be like below

put inside your activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Your `MainActivty.java`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

inside your `app.gradle` use `androidx` dependencys like below

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

I hope this will work for you, let me know if anything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use `setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar)` in here.

Comment: it do not give any error, only when i run the app it crashes it says Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Comment: You need to add this one.
`<activity
            android:name=".activities.YourMainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

in your AndroidManifest.xml

between <application> tag

Comment: where should i add dat?

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment, please look at it again.

Comment: did not work 
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.example.readytogo:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i got it i just need to changed this <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your XML you have something like this
[image]

Then you can proceed with something like this

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: i have this <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>